# jQuery plugin: callback option must return false(not working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

So I have build a plugin which has a callback option. This callback is used to work as a validation part so we use a 'return false' to stop the plugin but I cant get it to work.

So the **callback is working** but the return false is not(it must be a return false and not some kind of boolean variable)

//the callback

```
$('.a').click(function(){

   if(typeof options.onValidate == 'function'){
      options.onValidate.call(this);
   }
    // if the callback has a return false then it should stop here
    // the rest of the code
});
```

// options

```
....options = {
   // more options
   onValidate:function(){
      //some validation code
      return false;//not working
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
options.onValidate.call(this);
```

returns false, but it can't stop the execution of your click handler. You should use:

```
if(typeof options.onValidate == 'function'){
   var result = options.onValidate.call(this);
   if(result === false) return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the returned boolean value in your code. Try this:

```
$('.a').click(function() {
    var isValid = false;
    if (typeof options.onValidate == 'function'){
        isValid = options.onValidate.call(this);
    }

    if (isValid) {
        // if the callback has a return false then it should stop here
        // the rest of the code
    }
});
```